# Svn2Git rebase returns error 'too many arguments'

Tags: git, svn, migration, repository, svn2git

I managed to migrate a repository from SVN to GitLab via svn2git a couple days ago as a test.
I used svn2git because I needed a one way/cut over migration.

There have been some new commits on SVN (the Git repo remains untouched) since and I'm trying to update the resulting Git repository using `svn2git {REPO URL} --rebase` but it returns `Error starting script: Too many arguments`

I'd just like to know what might cause this error and how to avoid it and successfully update the Git repo without changing anything in the SVN repo.
I'm on Debian.

Answer (score 1):

The [svn2git script](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git/blob/6dac85ad12b74b478a926f09db0b110d73838702/lib/svn2git/migration.rb#L13-L16=) says:

```rb
    def initialize(args)
      @options = parse(args)
      if @options[:rebase]
         show_help_message('Too many arguments') if args.size > 0
         verify_working_tree_is_clean
```

So if you passed any parameters to a `svn2git --rebase` call, you would get that error.

A [repository update](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git#repository-updates=) should be:

> As of svn2git 2.0 there is a new feature to pull in the latest changes from SVN into your git repository created with svn2git.
> This is a one way sync, but allows you to use svn2git as a mirroring tool for your SVN repositories.
>
> The command to call is:
>
> ```
> $ cd <EXISTING_REPO> && svn2git --rebase
> ```